# Mac OS change creation and last modification dates of a folder

Tags: macos

What is the easiest way to change the creation and last modification dates of a folder (and recursively contained items) in Mac OS?

Comment: do you want to do this programmatically (via code, Objective-C, etc.) or Applescript or some other way?

Comment: Why 2 downvotes? This is a perfect good question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe following find/touch should work:

```
find /target/dir -exec touch '{}' \;
```

From `man touch`:

```
touch -- change file access and modification times
```

Comment: This doesn't change the creation date as reported by the Finder, only the modification date (observed on OS X 10.9.1).

Comment: `find path | xargs -I {} touch {}` looks simpler to me

Answer (score 18):

I am not sure whether this is problem with Mavericks or what, but `touch -mt` OR `touch -t` just update the modified and last opened  time.

Maybe `touch -mt` OR `touch -t` commands are working with 10.8.4 and earlier.

For Mavericks, I found solution as below.

```
SetFile -d '12/31/1999 23:59:59' file.txt
            MM dd yyyy hh mm ss  fileName
```

To update all files in folder just use

```
SetFile -d '12/31/1999 23:59:59' *
```

### [Reference](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99599)

Comment: To set the creation date/time to the date/time of a reference file, use `SetFile -d "$(GetFileInfo REFERENCEFILE | grep created | cut -c10-)" TARGETFILE`

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way would be using the *Terminal*:

```
// to change the creation date
touch -mt 201308030000 [pathtofile][filename]

// to change the modified date
touch -t 201308030000 [pathtofile][filename]
```

The date/time string is build like that:

- year *YYYY*
- month *MM*
- day *DD*
- hour *hh*
- minute *mm*

**Edit**

And for the recursive part, use what [anubhava suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18030890/1456376):

```
find [path] -exec touch -t 201308030000 {} \;
```

Comment: This only changes access and/or modification time, not creation time.

Answer (score 6):

For those who don't have XCode or developer tools installed and so cannot use `SetFile`, see below

1. `touch -m abc.txt` sets current time as modification time of abc.txt
2. `touch -mt YYYYMMDDhhmm abc.txt`sets YYYYMMDDhhmm as modification time of abc.txt
3. `touch -t YYYYMMDDhhmm abc.txt` sets YYYYMMDDhhmm as both access and modification time of abc.txt
4. More importantly, `touch` command is not designed to change file creation time. It appears, creation time is not a UNIX concept. `touch` is for changing file access and modification times. See [man](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/touch.1.html) page for `touch`.

Then **why `touch` changes creation time only some times** ? Reason is modification time cannot be *lesser* than creation time. *So when we set modification time to a date before creation time, the creation time is also set to modification time*. Two things now.

1. `touch -t` to an older date than creation time, sets both creation and modification time to older date.
2. `touch -t` to a newer date than creation time, sets only modification time to newer date. Creation time will remain unaffected. The best creation time can be reached by `cp oldfile newfile`, so that `newfile` has current time as creation time which can be then be reduced again with `touch -t`

`SetFile` works well with any date. In case it is not in `PATH` use as
 `xcrun SetFile -d '12/31/2099 23:59:59' abc.txt`

Answer (score 2):

From the terminal:

a) Creation date:

```
touch –t YYYYMMDDhhmm theFile
```

b) Modified date:

```
touch –mt YYYYMMDDhhmm the File
```

Examples:

```
touch –t 201308021025 theFile.txt
touch –mt 201308021026 theFile.txt
```

If you need to do on a set of files, use find & xargs

Answer (score 0):

In latest macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 running on 27" iMac (late 2019 model), directory listings through commands "ls -lt" and "ls -ltr" are exactly the same instead of reverse.

So I decided to use command "stat" to generate integer numbers correspond to modification dates instead of using unreliable "ls" command (correct me if I am wrong). I have created following non-recursive function in .bashrc configuration file in my home directory as alias "moddate" ready to be executed anytime  on any directory list as: "moddate *" for all folders in current directory. Note only folder make sense here but not file.

```
### Update parent folder's modification date taken from the newest child folder nested within.
    
function moddate {

    dir_list=$@

    for path in $dir_list
    do
        if [[ -d "${path}" ]]; then
            latest=`stat -f '%m %N' ${path}/* | sort -k1rn | awk '{print $2; exit}'`
            ls -ld $latest
            (set -x; touch -r "${latest}" "${path}")
        fi
    done
}
```